# Merging two list of dictionaries based on key

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict1 = [{'id': 1.0, 'name': 'aa'},
 {'id': 4.0, 'name': 'bb'},
 {'id': 2.0, 'name': 'cc'}]
```

and

```
dict2 = [{'name': 'aa', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 {'name': 'bb', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 {'name': 'xx', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 {'name': 'cc', 'dtype': 'StringType'}]
```

I would like to merge this two dictionaries based on their common `key` which is `name`.

I would like to get the following desired result.

```
merged_dict= [{'id': 1.0, 'name': 'aa', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 {'id': 4.0, 'name': 'bb', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 {'id': 2.0, 'name': 'cc', 'dtype': 'StringType'}]
```

I was trying to get this using the following for loop.

```
for i in dict1:
    for j in dict2:
         j.update(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid quadratic complexity, better first create a **real dictionary** (yours are lists of dictionaries), then `update`:

```
tmp = {d['name']: d for d in dict2}

for d in dict1:
    d.update(tmp.get(d['name'], {}))

print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1.0, 'name': 'aa', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 {'id': 4.0, 'name': 'bb', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 {'id': 2.0, 'name': 'cc', 'dtype': 'StringType'}]
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
{'aa': {'name': 'aa', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 'bb': {'name': 'bb', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 'xx': {'name': 'xx', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 'cc': {'name': 'cc', 'dtype': 'StringType'}}
```

If you want a copy (rather that modifying `dict1` in place):

```
tmp = {d['name']: d for d in dict2}
merged_dict = [d|tmp.get(d['name'], {}) for d in dict1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and try following:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
res = df1.merge(df2, on=['name'])
```

The output:

```
    id name       dtype
0  1.0   aa  StringType
1  4.0   bb  StringType
2  2.0   cc  StringType
```

If you need a dictionary, you can convert merged result `pd.DataFrame()` to `dict`.

```
res.to_dict('records')
```

Final output is:

```
[
  {'id': 1.0, 'name': 'aa', 'dtype': 'StringType'}, 
  {'id': 4.0, 'name': 'bb', 'dtype': 'StringType'}, 
  {'id': 2.0, 'name': 'cc', 'dtype': 'StringType'}
]
```